# Save Data from kd-tree in a pile on Pre-order with constant cost

Tags: java, kdtree

I have a little problem to implement a method that given a kdtree, stored in a stack all items ordered on pre-order.

I implemented this method iteratively, and I have this code:

```
public void preorder (Node <Pair <K,V>> node) throws SiguienteException {
     Stack <Pair <K,V>> stack = new Stack <Pair <K,V>> ();
     stack.stack (node.data ());
     while (! stack.isEmpty ()) {
     Pair <K,V> stack.getTop pair = ();
     stack.unstack ();
     if (pair! = null) {
     System.out.printf ("% s \ n", pair.getKey ());
     pila.apilar (node.getRigth (). data ());
     pila.apilar (node.getLeft (). data ());
     node.setDato (pair);

     }
     }

     }
```

The problem is that this method through the elements of the tree, and no longer has constant order, linear order, but in the worst case.

Can you think of any way to save the items in a stack with constant order?

Sorry if I have not explained well, I'm Spanish and I'm using the Google translator xD